# QTableView does not refresh foreign keys?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qt4.7, qsqltablemodel

I have a `QMainWindow` with two `QTableViews`on it.  Each `QTableView` has its own `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.  I am using `OnManualSubmit` as the edit strategy for both models.  Both models hit the same database, and are populated using `setTable` (each hits a different table), followed by `select()`.

The model for the second table is set up with appropriate calls to `setRelation` to link it to the table used to populate the first model.  On the second (child) view, I call `view->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(view));`

Everything seems to work great:  data that appears in the first view is listed in a drop-down in the appropriate field of the second view.

My issue:  when I add, edit, or delete a record to the first (parent) view and save it to the database, how should I refresh the second view so that the drop-down is accurate?

There may be unsaved edits in the second (child) view, and I don't want to lose those, nor do I want to save them yet.  I just want the drop-down list to be updated appropriately.

I tried `child_model->relationModel(fk_col)->select();` and that works, but `child_model->relationModel(fk_col)->columnCount();` indicates that the select is operating on all the fields of the parent table, which seems like unnecessary pessimization.

This is my first attempt using `<QtSql>` and `QTableView` so I may be missing something fundamental.  Maybe there is a way to use the same model for both views, and the refresh happens automatically?  What is the appropriate way for child view drop-downs to be refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query executed by `QSqlRelationalTableModel` doesn't contains the foreign keys anymore.

For example with this db structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries (id, name);
CREATE TABLE cities(id, name, id_country);
```

The query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT id, name, country_name FROM cities 
    LEFT JOIN countries ON id_country = countries.id;
```

Which means, the query has to be re-executed for the table to be updated, if the joined table changes.

To refresh automatically, I guess you would have:

- to use regular `QSqlTableModel` to keep the actual foreign keys in the model,
- to write a `QAbstractItemDelegate` class to display the mapped value and to create the `QComboBox` editor.
- to trigger a repaint of the mapped column area on the view whenever the first model changes.